# sqlfluff: How can I skip (not ignore) lines in a .sql file?

Tags: sqlfluff

I have a .sql file that I want to lint with sqlfluff. I have some lines in this sql file that are guaranteed to cause parse errors. Incidentally, these are `echo` commands - I have a weird `make` system that handles this without errors.
So I have

valid sql lines

echo "this breaks sqlfluff"

more valid sql .

`-- noqa` does not work. It only ignores the parse errors. The parse errors mean that actual lint errors from the rest of the file do not work.
Output: L:  12 | P:   1 |  PRS | Line 12, Position 1: Found unparsable section: 'echo

Any suggestions?